# How to remain in same user profile

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

So I have a register, login system which once the user logs in they are in their account.
From their account they can fill in other details on other pages i.e personal details form. Once they have filled these details in it should return them back to their account but obviously their details should be in mysql database in the personal table but links to their id in the users table (where registration details are stored)
I'm a bit stuck on the code that should be in my personal form which ensures the id is the same for the particular user.
Any help would be great

For example I have 'id' in both tables. I have made this auto inc. I also have a unique field in both called user_id which links the tables.

My personal php code:

```
include 'dbc.php';

$err = array();

if (!empty($_POST['doPersonal']) && $_POST['doPersonal'] == 'Submit') 
{ 
/******************* Filtering/Sanitizing Input *****************************
This code filters harmful script code and escapes data of all POST data
from the user submitted form.
*****************************************************************/
 foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
$data[$key] = filter($value);
}







$host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$host_upper = strtoupper($host);
$path   = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');

if(empty($err)) {

$sql_insert = "INSERT into `personal`
        (`sex`,`aux_citizen`,`birth_place`,`birth_country`,`children`
        )
        VALUES
          ('$data[sex]','$data[aux_citizen]','$data[birth_place]',
'$data[birth_country]','$data[children]'
        )
        ";

mysql_query($sql_insert,$link) or die("Insertion Failed:" . mysql_error());




header("Location: thankyou.php");  
exit();

 } 
}
```

Some Users (registration details) php code:

```
<?php 

include 'dbc.php';

$err = array();

if(@$_POST['doRegister'] == 'Register') 
 { 
   foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
$data[$key] = filter($value);
 }


$user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$sha1pass = PwdHash($data['pwd']);

$host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$host_upper = strtoupper($host);
$path   = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');

$usr_email = $data['usr_email'];
$user_name = $data['user_name'];



$birthday = date("Y-m-d", mktime(0,0,0,$dt,$mo,$yr));
if(empty($err)) {

$sql_insert = "INSERT into `users`
        (`full_name`,`user_email`,`pwd`,`nationality`,`department`
,`birthday`,`date`,`users_ip`,`activation_code`,`user_name`
        )
        VALUES
        ('$data[full_name]','$usr_email','$sha1pass'
,'$data[nationality]','$data[department]','$birthday'
        ,now(),'$user_ip','$activ_code','$user_name'
        )
        ";

mysql_query($sql_insert,$link) or die("Insertion Failed:" . mysql_error());
$user_id = mysql_insert_id($link);  
$md5_id = md5($user_id);
mysql_query("update users set md5_id='$md5_id' where id='$user_id'");
//  echo "<h3>Thank You</h3> We received your submission.";
?>
```

Comment: You should showcase the code snippets you have to help you

Answer (score 0):

What is your problem exactly? Keeping the ID in PHP, or linking the ID field from personal to the ID field from users?